# Run time differences between caret::train(method = 'neuralnet') vs. direct use of neuralnet()

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I'm attempting to train a neural network on some health economics data for regression. If I attempt to train directly using neuralnet() with the same parameters, it executes quickly. If I attempt the same using caret::train, it hangs for a long time.

I cannot share the data, but it is a data frame of dimensions 15000 by 29, with no missingness and all values are either numeric or integers and scaled.

If I attempt to train directly using neuralnet() with hidden = c(2,2) it completes in less than a minute (ignoring that the network is complete rubbish). i.e.

```
nn.LYS <- neuralnet(form.LYS,
                    data.all.scaled.train, 
                    hidden = c(2,2), 
                    lifesign = 'full')
```

However, when trying to train the same network using caret, it hangs for >20 minutes using the same R version, package versions, and hardware:

```
nn.LYS.grid <- expand.grid('layer1' = 2, 
                           'layer2' = 2, 
                           'layer3' = 0)

nn.LYS <- caret::train(form.LYS,
                       data.all.scaled.train, 
                       method = 'neuralnet'
                       tuneGird = nn.LYS.grid,
                       lifesign = 'full')
```

Does anybody have any experience with this or thoughts as to what is happening?

The caret version finally completed (~2 hours!)
Exited with the following warnings:

```
warning messages:
1: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, ... :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
2: In for (w in 1:length(nrow)) { .. :
  closing unused connection 28 (<-view-localhost:11599)
<... shortened ...>
17: In for (w in 1:length(nrow)) { .. :
  closing unused connection 29 (<-view-localhost:11599)
18: Algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repitition(s) within the stepmax.
```

These mostly just report closed cluster connections due to my parallelisation. This approach is consistent between the caret and neuralnet versions.

Interestingly, the direct neuralnet() version converged at step = 18364. Whereas the caret version didn't converge by stepmax = 1e5.

Comment: Caret is doing parameter tuning and other cross validation stuff so it is doing many many iterations of neuralnet which is why it takes so long.

Comment: caret is pretty old. Its successors are tidymodels and mlr3. The former, as the name suggests, comes from the tidyverse whereas the latter has its own ecosystem and utilizes data.table internally.